# Python 3 | My function wont print "No" after pressing 'N' or 'n'. It instead loops back to the beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, let me write down my code for you.

```
def AorB():

    with open('AB.txt', 'r+') as f:
        A = ['A', 'The Letter A']
        B = ['B', 'The Letter B']
        c = input('Write A or B >>>_ ')
        if c in A:
            print('You wrote A')
            add = input('Write Something Here! >>>_ ')
            f_contents = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(add + '\n')
            more_line = input('Would you like to write more lines? >>>_ ')
            if more_line == 'Y' or 'y':
                AorB()
            if more_line == 'N' or 'n':
                print('You wrote No!')
AorB()
```

What the result is...

```
Write A or B >>>_ (Wrote A)
You wrote A
Write Something Here! >>>_ (Writes Something.)
Would you like to write more lines? >>>_ (Wrote N)
Write A or B >>>_
```

As you can see it looped back to the beginning. my desired result is

```
Write A or B >>>_ (Wrote A)
You wrote A
Write Something Here! >>>_ (Prints something.)
Would you like to write more lines? >>>_ (N)
You wrote No!
```

Comment: Pro tip: `more_line.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Close, you just need to change the syntax a bit. Try this

```
if more_line == 'N' or more_line == 'n':
```

and you'll want to change this one too

```
if more_line == 'Y' or more_line =='y':
```

Explanation:

Python is translating `if more_line == 'Y' or 'y':` into this `if more_line == 'Y' or if 'y' then do some stuff`. The second part (`if 'y'`) is always true so the rest doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: The same problem still persists.[Edit, Nevermind I got it.]

Comment: Cool, i added an explanation if you're interested